# new starcluster release broke setting up of nfs

Tags: starcluster

I just upgraded starcluster to use modern machines and I now get the following traceback. Previous versions work fine with identical configs.  What changes need to made to the config for it to work?  It looks like it is exporting a file that does not exist on modern ubuntu servers.  (I asked this question on github and no one has had a solution)

http://pastebin.com/Ur4HD48y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a number of packages have to be changed to get current ubuntu to work with current starcluster.

Need to create a new ami using the following steps:

log in to an ubuntu ami
and run the following commands:

1. apt-get update
2. apt-get install nfs-kernel-server nfs-common portmap
3. sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server /etc/init.d/nfs
4. apt-get install python-scipy python-numpy
5. ln -s /lib/init/upstart-job /etc/init.d/portmap
6. ln -s /lib/init/upstart-job /etc/init.d/portmap-wait
7. wget http://dl.dropbox.com/u/47200624/respin/ge2011.11.tar.gz
8. tar xvf ge2011.11.tar.gz
9. mv ge2011.11 /opt/sge6-fresh

Comment: Hi, I've created an ami from an ubuntu system but now qsub is not installed ... I am missing something ??